# Authenticating web API by SAML token passed to it

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, saml-2.0, ws-federation, adfs3.0

I have a Web API on premise (exposed on https) which is called by an external application. This application passes a SAML token (by signing to ADFS 3.0). I need to authenticate the user in Web API using this SAML token and then return the values.

I am aware that SAML is not the best option but the calling application can only send me the SAML token. So I have limited option here.

I was able to add a relaying party in ADFS for my Web API (With WSFed endpoint as my local url) and when I ran the Web API locally from IIS (In browser) then I am able to log in (on ADFS page) and authenticate and get values (With Claims)

So what I did is try to create a Console application that can get a SAML token and then try and pass the SAML token to call the Web API.

Below is the code I am using :

```
   static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            const string relyingPartyId = "https://localhost/api/"
            const string adfsEndpoint = "https://adfsserver/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed";

            const string certSubject = "CN=<domain>";



            //Setup the connection to ADFS

            var factory = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), new EndpointAddress(adfsEndpoint))

            {

                TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13

            };



            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";

            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

            factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;



            //Setup the request object 

            var rst = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.RequestSecurityToken

            {

                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,

                KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,

                AppliesTo = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(relyingPartyId)

            };



            //Open a connection to ADFS and get a token for the logged in user

            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

            var genericToken = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;



            if (genericToken != null)

            {


                var samlAssertion = genericToken.TokenXml.OuterXml;




                Check(samlAssertion);



            }



        }

static async void Check(string samlAssertion)

        {

            try

            {

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                HttpRequestMessage request =

                    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost/api/Values");

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", samlAssertion);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);



                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }

            catch(Exception de)

            {

                throw de;

            }

        }
```

This fails when calling "client.SendAsync(...."

I have two question(s):

1. How do I make this work ?
2. Currently we are using a Local ADFS so I get the XML SAML token (readable), but when in production I will get an encrypted SAML token. What changes do I have to make in Web API in case of encrypted SAML token.

I need some help and directions here. Any sample code or blogs would definitely help.

- Girija